# Formatting milliseconds smartly

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

I have a query that summarizes some data that is in milliseconds:

```
requests
| summarize avg(duration) by name
```

When I display this data, I would like to format it so that it shows the amount of time in a smart way:

Examples:

- 1500 would display 1.5 sec
- 300 would display 300 ms
- 120000 would display 2 min

I know that the built in graphs for Application Insights does this in the Performance tab, but I can't find a built in function that does it. Does anyone know if there is a function that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

below is one option, using `timespan` arithmetics and some string manipulation

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic

alternatively - if it suits your requirements - you can use `format_timespan()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-timespanfunction

```
let format_ms_as_pretty_string = (t:long)
{
    case(t < 1s / 1ms, strcat(t, " ms"),
         t < 1m / 1ms, strcat(round(1.0 * t * 1ms / 1s, 3), " secs"),
         t < 1h / 1ms, strcat(round(1.0 * t * 1ms / 1m, 3), " mins"),
         strcat(round(1.0 * t * 1ms / 1h, 3), " hours"))
}
;
let input = datatable(t:long) [1500,300,120000,8481600,360100] // replace this with your input
;
input
| extend output = format_ms_as_pretty_string(t)
```

| t | output |
| --- | --- |
| 1500 | 1.5 secs |
| 300 | 300 ms |
| 120000 | 2.0 mins |
| 8481600 | 2.356 hours |
| 360100 | 6.002 mins |